# GPG not decrypting symmetrically encrypted file

Tags: gpg, pgp

I have data which I encrypted using `gpg -ac --cipher-algo AES256 data` and a passphrase. I moved that file onto a different machine with `gpg` as well, but unlike the system it was encrypted on (TrueOS), it doesn't have a GUI installed. When I try to decrypt the file using `gpg -d -o data.d data` I get these errors:

- `gpg: AES256 encrypted data`
- `gpg: problem with the agent: End of file`
- `gpg:encrypted with 1 passphrase`
- `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key`

My file looks like this:

`-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
data in here
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----`

I tried the opposite: encrypting a file. I made one and added random text, and tried to encrypt it using `gpg -a --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 data1`
and got this output:

- `gpg: problem with the agent: End of file`
- `gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled`
- `gpg: symmetric encryption of '' failed: Operation cancelled`
  This is quite strange. I suspect it has something to do with pinentry; I had appended this line to my `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` : `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty`

Comment: I'm assuming the last bits you tried ("the opposite") was on the Tru64 system? Do you have pinentry installed in the configured location there?

Comment: No, it wasn't, it was on the same ArchLinux system that I tried to decrypt it on.

Comment: The encryption command writes to `data.asc`. Did you rename it to `data`? From your description it looks like you're trying to decrypt the original plaintext file.